# Android How to change layout option from Material Design to standard android

Tags: android, dependencies

Im beginner to Android (and programming too) and Im following one of the tutorial how to make an Android app using Material Desing. Unfortunately as the tutorial was made two years ago it looks like the newer version of Android have dropped the dependency Im looking for (roundIcon). How to change the layout from MD into the standard android?

Below there is  my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gosia.animalsystem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gosia.animalsystem.AnimalSystemActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the styles.xml check for the appTheme.
Currently it must be an AppCompatTheme

Change that to Any HOLO theme.

Hope this helps.